# How to ignore scripts, style etc when loading in Angularjs ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i'm using Angularjs and I have a ng-view with some parts. The partial views have some scripts in the head.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
<body>

 <div class="section">
      ... some content
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i load a view those scripts are loaded too.

```html
<div style="" class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
  <meta class="ng-scope" charset="utf-8">
  <script class="ng-scope" type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="section ng-scope">
    .. some view content.
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using an HTML Editor for Twitter Bootstrap to edit views quickly and this tool needs the html, head and body tags. And I don't want to remove them from templates. Is it posible to ignore the head tag of partial view when it's loaded?

Comment: You could use ng-if condition

Comment: How can prevent the loading of meta/script tags with ng-if?

Comment: Are you sure that the editor cannot be configured to not use html and body tags? Which editor do you use?

Comment: @hege_hegedus No, it cannot. I use Pingendo. It's a really simple tool.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a ng-view, isn't better to create a **directive** with your template in, and use the compile() or in the link() phase to remove the bad tags ?

Afaik directives are the good way to alter the DOM.
I'm not really familiar with the compile() but I let you read this post if you are interested in : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2794-when-do-you-need-to-compile-a-directive-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: There are a lot of views and I also load controllers for them etc with routProvider. I don't want to do it more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I took a look into templateRequestProvider and httpProvider. And Here is my solution.

```html
app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

  ....  

  function appendTransform(defaults, transform) {

    // We can't guarantee that the default transformation is an array
    defaults = angular.isArray(defaults) ? defaults : [defaults];

    // Append the new transformation to the defaults
    return defaults.concat(transform);
  }
  /**
  * My HTML Template transformation
  */
  function doTransform(value){
    if(angular.isString(value)){
      return value.replace(/<head>(.|\n)*<\/head>/mg,"");
    }
    return value;
  }

  $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse = appendTransform($httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse,
    function(value) {
      return doTransform(value);
  });

})
```

It's not a best solution because it would filter each http request. Better to apply it only for ng-view. It should work with templateRequestProvider.httpOptions but only with angular 1.5+.